# HOW can i sum a categorical variable and aggregate by factor

Tags: r, sum, aggregate, factors, summarize

So let me be a little more specific.....
i have a dataset that has

1. SOCCERTEAM   -PLAYERS
2. BARCA - MESSI
3. BARCA   - MESSI
4. BARCA   - MESSI
5. BARCA   - XAVI
6. -RM  -  CR
7. -RM -  CR
8. -RM  -  PEPE
9. -RM -HIQUAIN
   etc(just an example not dataset)

as columns!!!

I want the answer to this question :
**" How can i find the top 5 teams according to how many players they used"**
*teams can use players more than once so finding the factor levels are not a possibility
*so if barca used 15 players and Rm used 14 then BARCA is first.....

Comment: Try `library(data.table);head(setDT(df1)[, .(n = uniqueN(PLAYERS)), SOCCERTEAM][order(-n)]$SOCCERTEAM, 5)`

Comment: @akrun thnx for the help...it worked even though i can't really find the use of the part: .....[, .(n = uniqueN(PLAYERS)), SOCCERTEAM][order(-n)]$SOCCERTEAM, 5)...    why after setDT(df1) we use [  ]  ?

Comment: You should probably take a look at [Getting Started with `data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(SOCCERTEAM) %>% 
  summarize(rank = n_distinct(PLAYERS)) %>%
  top_n(5, wt = rank)
```

Comment: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : invalid subscript type 'list'

Comment: Maybe try renaming 'rank' to something else. So `summarize(n_players = n_distinct(PLAYERS)) %>% top_n(5, n_players)`